Collision checking from joint state
I'm trying to check collision from a specific joint configuration. I followed the  Planning Scene ROS API tutorial to add a collision box and Planning scene to check for robot collisions.
With my code below, even though the collision box is at (0, 0, 0), moveIt does not detect any collisions. Have I made a mistake ?
Thank you for your help.
bool Robot::checkCollision(const std::vector<double> &joint_positions) {

if (!box_init) {
    moveit_msgs::CollisionObject collision_object;
    collision_object.header.frame_id = "base_link";
    collision_object.id = "obstacle";

    shape_msgs::SolidPrimitive primitive;
    primitive.type = primitive.BOX;
    primitive.dimensions.resize(3);
    primitive.dimensions[0] = 0.5; // x
    primitive.dimensions[1] = 0.5; // y
    primitive.dimensions[2] = 0.5; // z

    geometry_msgs::Pose box_pose;
    box_pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
    box_pose.position.x = 0.5;
    box_pose.position.y = 0.0;
    box_pose.position.z = 0;

    collision_object.primitives.push_back(primitive);
    collision_object.primitive_poses.push_back(box_pose);
    collision_object.operation = collision_object.ADD;

    ros::Publisher planning_scene_diff_publisher = node_handle.advertise<moveit_msgs::PlanningScene>("planning_scene", 1);
    ros::WallDuration sleep_t(0.5);
    while (planning_scene_diff_publisher.getNumSubscribers() < 1)
    {
        sleep_t.sleep();
    }

    moveit_msgs::PlanningScene planning_scene;
    planning_scene.world.collision_objects.push_back(collision_object);
    planning_scene.is_diff = true;
    planning_scene_diff_publisher.publish(planning_scene);

    box_init = true;
}
robot_model_loader::RobotModelLoader robot_model_loader("robot_description");
const moveit::core::RobotModelPtr& kinematic_model = robot_model_loader.getModel();
planning_scene::PlanningScene planning_scene(kinematic_model);

moveit::core::RobotState& current_state = planning_scene.getCurrentStateNonConst();
const moveit::core::JointModelGroup* joint_model_group = current_state.getJointModelGroup("manipulator");

current_state.setJointGroupPositions(joint_model_group, joint_positions);

collision_detection::CollisionRequest collision_request;
collision_detection::CollisionResult collision_result;
collision_request.contacts = true;
collision_request.max_contacts = 1000;

planning_scene.checkCollision(collision_request, collision_result, current_state, planning_scene.getAllowedCollisionMatrix());

if (collision_result.collision) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}

